# Google analytics for android ignores setDebug

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using beta 4 of google analytics V2 within my android app. For convenience I'm wrapping it in a separate class (singleton) like this:

```
private AnalyticsTracker(Context context) {

    GAServiceManager.getInstance().setDispatchPeriod(5);
    GoogleAnalytics googleAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);

    googleAnalytics.setDebug(true);

    tracker = googleAnalytics.getTracker(context.getString(R.string.ga_trackingId));
}
```

For further usage I use the EasyTracker for activity tracking and the tracker member variable for event tracking.

```
public void onActivityStart(Activity activity) {
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(activity);
}

public void onActivityStop(Activity activity) {
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(activity);
}

public void trackEvent(AnalyticsEvent event) {
    tracker.sendEvent(event.category, event.action, event.label, 0L);
    GAServiceManager.getInstance().dispatch();
}
```

The problem is that setDebug(true) in the constructor seems to be ignored as there is no output on LogCat and my interaction appears in the reports. I'm not setting the debug flag in the analytics.xml.

If I do so and set the flag to true in the xml file it works as expected and analytics logs the events to LogCat.

Any idea why it ignores the call from the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use    `<bool name="ga_debug">false</bool>`  in analytics.xml in values folder for enableing disabling debug.

analytics.xml:

```
<!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-123456-2</string>

<!-- Enable automatic activity tracking -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

<!-- Enable debug -->
<bool name="ga_debug">false</bool>

<!-- The screen names that will appear in your reporting -->
<string name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity">any name</string>

<!--The inverval of time after all the collected data  should be sent to the server, in seconds.-->
<integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>
```

Ref: [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/)

Comment: Of course I tried that as well, but even though I set debug to true my data appears in the reports...